# c++ code does not compile with strange error

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

This piece of c++ code does not compile. Anybody knows why?

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int a, char** v) {

        std::vector<uint32_t> v1 {1,2,3,4};
        std::vector<uint32_t> v2 {0};
        std::vector<uint32_t> v3 {5,4,3,11};
        std::vector<uint32_t> v4 {10,11,2};


        auto vector_is_subset = [] (const std::vector<uint32_t> a, const std::vector<uint32_t> b) -> bool {

                std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
                std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
                return std::includes(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
        };


        std::vector<uint32_t> f {};

        if (v1.empty() || v2.empty() || v3.empty() || v4.empty() ){
                std::cout << "a vector is empty" << std::endl;
        }


        return 0;
}
```

I got the following output

**g++ a.cpp -std=c++14**

In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62:0,
                 from a.cpp:2:

> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void
>   std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator,
>   _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’:
>   /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:1885:25:   required from ‘void
>   std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator,
>   _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
>   /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:1971:31:   required from ‘void
>   std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare)
>   [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Compare =
>   __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’ /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4836:18:   required from ‘void
>   std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >]’ a.cpp:16:31:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:1852:17: error: assignment of
>   read-only location ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >::operator*()’
>           *__first = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__val);

Comment: You try to sort a vector which declared to be a constant one?

Comment: In those kind of questions, there are always be a cpp guy that will downvote. Even if the code is completed, compile directive, compile error. Everything is include, is a precise question. I don't really care for the downvote, but I just wanted to point this out.

Comment: @CaptainNemo, isn’t it supposed to not compile with a strange error?

Comment: recently I got an "expected expression before …". IMO this is not a strange error.

Comment: @CaptainNemo You forgot the "minimal" attribute of a [mre]. That's why a cpp guy will downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::sort` modifies the container to make it sorted, but you declared parameters of your lambda as `const`:

```
auto vector_is_subset = [] (const std::vector<uint32_t> a, const std::vector<uint32_t> b) -> bool
                         // ^^^^                           ^^^^^
```

remove them and it should compile fine.